# appsettings.json read properly when deployed as Azure Function App Container, but not when deployed as simply Azure Function App

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, serverless

I have a Function App which is successfully running locally and successfully running as "Azure Function App Container",
but when I'm trying to deploy it as simply "Azure Function App", right after publishing it can't read the fields that I put in the appsettings.json file (I put there s3 key access and secret key among other things), the error that is shown is that "No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured", which should be taken from the appsettings.json file.
This is what happens in my startup class:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
           .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), false)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .Build();

        builder.Services.AddLogging();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(svc =>
           {
               var client = new AzureLogAnalyticsClient(
                 config[LogAnalyticsWorkspaceID],
                 config[LogAnalyticsKey]);
               client.TimeStampField = config["LogAnalyticsTimestampField"];
               return client;
           });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Azure Function App deployment will not read appsettings.json by default. Instead, put those configuration values in the Azure Function's application settings.

This can be done by logging into the Azure portal, going to your Azure Function, then:

1. Click "Configuration" on the Azure Function blade.
2. Choose Application Settings in the header.
3. Enter your settings in the table below.

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution but it worked!
But is there any possibility to force Function App deployment to read appsettings.json?

Comment: Functions can read local.settings.json in Azure, but when we did this, it was a giant pain in the *** of trying to code around the default behavior. We eventually abandoned it due to the complexity of the solution and went with using Microsoft's App Configuration service and Keyvault, which fit our needs much better. 
If this is helpful, please mark as the answer and upvote.